# Not Able to Check if Iframe is Empty or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Can you please take a look at **[This Pen](https://codepen.io/behseini/pen/NWaJoGg?editors=1111)** and let me know why I am getting wrong output (`"iFrame is Empty"`) while the `#this-frame` is already populated with

```
$("#this-frame").contents().find("body").text("iFrame Lorem ...!");
```

and is not empty! Here is the code

```
<iframe id="this-frame"></iframe>

$(function() {
  $("#this-frame").contents().find("body").text("iFrame Lorem ...!");

  setTimeout(() => {
     if ($("#this-frame").contents().find("body").length) {
        console.log("iFrame is Empty");
       } else {
         console.log("iFrame is not Empty");
    }
   }, 500);

});
```

Comment: The logic in your question is working. The issue is simply because the `console.log` statements in your `if` condition are backwards. Voting to close as a typographical issue –

Comment: `.find("body").length` is saying does it have a body element. It is not looking at what is in the body.